# Replace ZooKeeper servers

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, bigdata

I want to replace current 3 ZooKeeper servers with 3 new ZooKeeper servers. I have added:

- new Zoo to Ambari,
- add new Zoo to variables:

  `hbase.zookeeper.quorum
   ha.zookeeper.quorum
   zookeeper.connect
   hadoop.registry.zk.quorum
   yarn.resourcemanager.zk-address`

Restart services, restart RM, and still I can't connect to any new Zoo when I turn off all old Zoo servers.

zookeeper-client -server zoo-new1
I get the following error:

"Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket"

And on new Zoo server in logs (zookeeper.out):

"Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: ZooKeeperServer not running"

When I run one of the old ZooKeepers, then everything is working, and I can connect also to the new ZooKeeper servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that this has to do with one of the most important properties in zookeeper, namely leader election. If you start with a zookeeper quorum with 3 servers and add 3 more servers to it. You will have to have at least 4 servers running for the quorum to be accessible. When a zookeeper node was unable to elect a leader it will look as if it's down.

This is also the reason why your setup works when you start one of the old zookeepers, because they are now 4 alive of 6 possible. If you want the new setup to work you need to remove the old servers from the config, so that the quorum only knows about the three new ones. To simply shut a zookeeper server down will not remove it from the quorum.